# Application select greyed out. Azure AD B2C - Identity experience framework

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I was simply following this guide:
[Get started with custom policies in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-get-started)
Following all the previous instructiones without a problem. I got to "Test the custom policy" where I got stuck. When I open any of my custom policies it is a same story. Application select and select reply url is greyed out.
Any idea what might cause it?

Sreenshot of my problem:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrPkG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please create a B2C application registration.And you can refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-applications?tabs=app-reg-ga).